# Get used languages statistic from TFS

Tags: tfs, metrics, code-metrics

I'm new on TFS SDK, and I demand is there a possible way to get a statistic of used langages on a project hosted on TFS 2012 "Programmatically" ?

like on github :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could probably write your own by accessing a specific solution, (possibly) downloading and 'counting' the number of language resource files.

It is likely that this is similar to what is happening above, it is certainly not a method that I am aware of within TFS.

Comment: Indeed, GitHub uses their project, Linguist, to do these calculations:  https://github.com/github/linguist.